# Toggle classes in react styled components with react-responsive library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am using react styled components and want to create a toggle functionality or the Link components.

The first step I took was to create the useMediaQueries hook and use min-width and max-width to delimit the pixels.

```
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'
    // Media queries
    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 700px)' });
    const isMobile  = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 700px)' });
```

After this, I created the styled components and moved them into separate file called `Header.styles.js`:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";


export const LinkStyled = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
`;

export const LinkWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    
`;

export const HeaderWrapper = styled.header`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
`;
```

The header use the media queries hook and display/hide the menu button and the header wrapper:

```
// Toggle state
    const [ isVisible, setIsvisible ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <HeaderWrapper>
        <p>Expenses</p>

        {isDesktop && <LinkWrapper isMobileVersion={isMobile}>
            <LinkStyled to='/'>Home</LinkStyled>
            <LinkStyled to='/about'>About</LinkStyled>
            <LinkStyled to='/profile'>Profile</LinkStyled>
            <LinkStyled to='/signup'>Signup</LinkStyled>
            <LinkStyled to='/login'>Login</LinkStyled>
        </LinkWrapper>}
        
        { isMobile && <GiHamburgerMenu size={25} onClick={() => setIsvisible(!isVisible)} /> }
    </HeaderWrapper>
  )
}
```

I am new to styled components. How can I toggle the classes or assign a class (created in the styled components file) only when the display is set on mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where exactly you wanna use it, but basically you can use ternary operator.

```
<LinkWrapper style={{ color: isMobile ? "#333" : "#444" }} />
```

*This code is just an example how to solve your problem*

Styled components are not just styles, but whole customized components.